# Stop columns from stacking under col-xs-* size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, col

I have a website that I am working on that has a simple widget that shows the current status of certain systems. The problem I am having is that when the view goes to mobile (iPhone size about) or the screen on a browser is creating the same effect, the rows that have objects in them start to stack and become invisible or cut off. I don't want these to ever stack because the design doesn't make sense that way. Is there a way to make is so something will never stack? I can't seem to get any clues as to how to fix this since the bootstrap choices don't go that small. It seems like it would work if there was a col-xxs-* class or a col-mobile-* class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I was having is there was a custom `div` class that was put into the hosting software's global styling. This `class` duplicated the idea of the Bootstrap col classes. It started from `col-all-12` to `col-all-1`. The problem is this would override all the other bootstrap styling and make things a certain size no matter what width the screen is. I appropriately adjusted these and it seems to work. I had to rebuild this code from scratch but now it is good!

Thank you to all those that helped and gave suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize twitter media query breakpoints
so the col-xs-* can start from 200px instead of 480px for example.

here is the link:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Edit the variables and download that version. you can also use bootstrap Less to edit these variables in your project as it suites you instead of re-downloading the files every time.

Comment: The only problem with this is the website is hosted through Ingeniux and I only have influence over a small portion of the system. Is there a way to override the existing parameters for the col-xs-* classes within the css or javascript areas?

Comment: you can add a css style to override the whole thing, but it is not good at all as it is a huge overhead.

Comment: follow the link, download the css file with your specifications, then put it in your head tag. but i dont recommend this approach..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps,

Make sure the viewport is configured correctly:

Make sure you don't have content that is wider than the viewport.

For instance if you have an image that is wider than the viewport set the CSS to

max-width:100%;

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you don't want to stack the divs one below the other in mobile view.  Then try to use  class like `table-responsive` that allows the content to appear with a horizontal scroll bar.

Then you have to set the min-width for those columns that you don't want to wrap. 
Or white-space:nowrap

Comment: It's not main content that is being stacked. It is content that should only exist in a row among other rows within a widget on the main area of the page. It is supposed to be viewable at all times.